# opencv-python(V4.2.0.32) imread code doesn't work in python(pycharm for win)

Tags: pycharm, imread, opencv, python

I coded for reading image and show as followings, but don't work without any debugging error notice. please solve it. thanks.

```
import cv2

img_basic = cv2.imread('screen1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow('Screen1', img_basic) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code everything seems fine. 
Probably the path of "screen1.jpg" is not correct. If you check the [documentation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image), there is a warning that says:

> Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but print img will give you None

So, for this reason, I think that the issue is the image path that is not correct.

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution. I checked the path tried more, but failed.

Comment: If I can code as followings? import cv2

img = r'C:\Users\mhyon\PycharmProjects\untitled1\screen1.jpg'
img1 = cv2.imread(img, 0)
cv2.imshow('Screen2', img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Comment: Done finally. the reason is the selestion of run method. it should be select the correct project and run. no code error.